# Wordpress: how to make a post template with a fix image placement?

Tags: wordpress

I am building a simple WP theme, but now I am stuck.  I need to add an image on a fixed place for `post_template A` and 2 images on `post_template B`

Like so:

```
title
img
date
content

title
img img
date
content
```

Is it possible to make a template and on the admin side have the corresponding # of upload fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with custom fields...

In the edit page view add a custom field called "img1" for instance and the value should be the image url.
Then in your template A file you can output the image with:

```
<?php
$myimage = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'img1', true); 

if ($myimage) { ?>
<img src="<?php echo $myimage; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

And in template B you just do that 2 times ;)

Comment: WOW that looks promising. So the only thing is after i have uploaded the image i need to copy the image url, right
gonna try it out

tx